# I can't connect to Minecraft servers with custom Port

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

So, here's the deal, I use a mobile application called netshare so that I connect to my router using my phone and then the phone creates a group so that I can connect to it using PC (Kinda like a WiFi extender), I need to do this because my PC has a much smaller wifi range compared to my phone, the issue is that the netshare application needs me to use a proxy:-
Ip : 192.168.49.1
Port : 8282
But when I use this proxy I can't at all seem to be able to connec, to any Minecraft servers. Guys, I really need your help in resolving this issue cause I have no idea what to do about it

Comment: If your phone has a WiFi signal while sitting on your desk you can simply use USB tethering instead of some extra app. This would work via Bluetooth as well. This way you have a clear connection with no proxy in between.

Comment: Cant use USB tethering cause then my phone loses connection, My phone says can't use Bluetooth tethering while wifi is on.

Comment: I just tested USB tethering and it works as expected. I can share the phone's WiFi with my PC just fine. Bluetooth tethering not working is a hardware issue when the same network adapter is used for both signals. If you have so much trouble getting a connection why not using a normal range extender or a cable or even power line adapters? Playing Minecraft won't be the only problem you run into when using such an unreliable network.

Comment: @marsian8 USB tethering is different from BT tethering. @ dly: This person might not have an own income for extra hardware yet.

Comment: @dly I actually ordered 2 hardware wifi mesh extenders online but you know they can't be delivered to me right now, due to recent events and this is the time I need to play Minecraft the most ;p

Comment: by loses connection, I mean 'gets out of range'. My bad

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question: It sounds like netshare is a proxy server. That means that it has to receive the requests as a "server", understand them, and then make requests to the actual server on your behalf. This is easy with common protocols (like http or https), but it very likely does not understand the protocol that Minecraft uses.

Here is another app that might work (disclaimer, I have never used it) It looks like it has a WiFi repeater mode:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.mygod.vpnhotspot&hl=en_US

The right answer to your problem is to fix the networking issues. It sounds like you need to run a cable(best option imo for gaming), buy range extenders, or otherwise get a stable connection to your router.