# Minecraft on a proxy server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't have access to an actual internet connection nor mobile hotspots, but I have unlimited data on my phone. Because of this, I'm using NetShare to extend wifi to my laptop. It works wonderfully for web browsers, Discord, etc., but Minecraft won't recognize I'm online - and if I run the game anyway, every server gives me an "unknown host" or "can't resolve hostname" error. I feel like if I can get this much working, Minecraft should run just fine, but I can't figure out a solution.

The way NetShare works is by turning on my phone's "Wi-Fi Direct" function, then going into my computer's connection settings to set up a proxy.

> Address: 192.168.49.1
>
> Port: 8282

I've seen a couple [(1)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/367639/i-cant-connect-to-minecraft-servers-with-custom-port) [(2)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21848/how-can-i-play-minecraft-through-a-proxy-server) of posts similar to what I'm looking for, but I can't get the .bin file working (likely because it's so outdated... or maybe because I'm not knowledgeable enough to know where/what info to plug), and I can't root my phone as far as I'm aware (LG Aristo 3+) to try other apps.

I've also tried following basic tips such as [this](https://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/unknown-host-errorcant-resolve-host-name-client-fix-17-all-platforms/#:%7E:text=This%20bug%20has%20nothing%20to,the%20%22Unknown%20Host%22%20error.) to resolve the issue - no avail. I know the connection won't be as speedy as normal Wi-Fi regardless, but I'm kinda desperate at this point.

Comment: Have you been able to connect to these servers previously without any issue?

Comment: On actual connections, yes. With this method, not at all.